# allow specific user to access specific pages in custom module

Tags: 8, users

I have created a custom module with custom database table in drupal 8 site. 
It has add, update, list and search pages.

I want to restrict as only admin or sub-admin can access the add, edit, list pages. Any user(non-registered also) can access the search page.

How to achieve this in the module i have developed itself in drupal 8? Or is there any common way in drupal 8 to add permission for a particular URL?

Comment: What type are those pages? Entities or something totally custom?

Comment: It is totally custom page. all pages are forms. created by referred this http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/step-by-step-method-to-create-a-custom-form-in-drupal-8 link. I created all the page using the forms

Comment: Then I think that you need something like this https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes

Comment: Why not just add permission checks in the route definitions?

Comment: thanks @Ismini . I used `_role` to specify roles. and `_access` to set publicly accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that through routing.yml file. Thanks for the comments. I posted this just for reference that may help someone else.

```
notices.notices_form:
  path: '/notices/addupdate'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\notices\Form\NoticesAddUpdateForm'
    _title: 'Notices Form'
  requirements:
    _role: 'administrator'

notices.notices_search_form:
  path: '/notices/search'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\notices\Form\NoticesSearchForm'
    _title: 'Search Notices'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```